# Dynamic fields in JSP: what is the best way?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have an old old app that we are updating.
It has a handful of dynamic fields that can be hidden/shown based on a value in a property file.
Custom tags were used to build the pages reading from those to know what to show.
What would be a better way to do this?
The field values could be moved to a database table so they could be set without redeploying the application.
Need something that can be used by both the client and server sides.

Comment: clarify your question what do you mean with : Custom tags were used to build the pages reading from those to know what to show ?

Answer (score 0):

Storing the field values in the database sounds like a good idea.  You could set these values in hidden input fields and use them in the client side javascirpt as well.